# Scale images excluding corners to make large windows

Tags: android

I do have a small 100X100 texture for my game, what my question is can i scale that image excluding its corner so that i can make different size window out of it. I am attaching the image so that u will have a better understanding, any help is appreciated, thanks :hug:
[image]

Comment: You can. convert your image into a `9-patch` image.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the tool to create 9 patch images

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Try this. It should work.

Comment: Thanks :hug: i didn't know its term :hug: